# libgazebo_ros_skid_steer_drive syntax for URDF in ROS2?

Tags: gazebo, ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi! I'm fairly new to gazebo, robot modelling and plugins, and I'm now trying to make a small 4wd rover, but I have some problems with the plugins. I'm not able to make the `libgazebo_ros_skid_steer_drive` plugin work in my `urdf` file in ROS2, and I get the following error msg:

`[gazebo-1] [Err] [Plugin.hh:212] Failed to load plugin libgazebo_ros_skid_steer_drive.so: libgazebo_ros_skid_steer_drive.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

This is what I have tried to put in my urdf file, but it is only a copy from the sdf version found in gazebo-ros-pkg. I have tried other syntax versions aswell, but with no luck.

```
    <gazebo>
    <plugin name="two_wheeled_robot_diff_drive" filename="libgazebo_ros_skid_steer_drive.so">
    <ros>
      <namespace>/demo</namespace>
      <remapping>cmd_vel:=cmd_demo</remapping>
      <remapping>odom:=odom_demo</remapping>
    </ros>

    <!-- Number of wheel pairs -->
    <num_wheel_pairs>2</num_wheel_pairs>
    
    <!-- wheels0 -->
    <left_joint>left_wheel_joint0</left_joint>
    <right_joint>right_wheel_joint0</right_joint>

    <!-- wheels1-->
    <left_joint>left_wheel_joint1</left_joint>
    <right_joint>right_wheel_joint1</right_joint>

    <!-- kinematics -->
    <wheel_separation>1.25</wheel_separation>
    <wheel_separation>1.25</wheel_separation>

    <wheel_diameter>1.0</wheel_diameter>
    <wheel_diameter>0.6</wheel_diameter>

    <!-- limits -->
    <max_wheel_torque>20</max_wheel_torque>
    <max_wheel_acceleration>1.0</max_wheel_acceleration>

    <!-- output -->
    <publish_odom>true</publish_odom>
    <publish_odom_tf>true</publish_odom_tf>
    <publish_wheel_tf>true</publish_wheel_tf>

    <odometry_frame>odom_demo</odometry_frame>
    <robot_base_frame>chassis</robot_base_frame>
     <plugin>
    <gazebo>
```

I have installed ros-foxy-gazebo-ros-pkgs and I can make the libgazebo_ros_diff_drive plugin work. Can anyone help me to fix the problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/392970/libgazebo_ros_skid_steer_drive-syntax-for-urdf-in-ros2?/) by [knuttu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91691/knuttu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2021-12-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So it turns out that the libgazebo_ros_skid_steer_drive plugin was [replaced](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/wiki) with the libgazebo_ros_diff_drive plugin from ROS1 to ROS2. In other words, the parameters in my file were right, but the filename wasnt. When I changed it to

```
filename="libgazebo_ros_diff_drive.so">
```

it worked perfectly.

---

Originally posted by [knuttu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91691/knuttu/) with karma: 36 on 2021-12-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-12-20**:
Glad it worked. Thank you for sharing your answer

Answer (score 0):

Is ROS2 `libgazebo_ros_skid_steer_drive.so` was [replaced](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/wiki) by `libgazebo_ros_diff_drive.so`.

Now you can add more pairs of wheels by specifying `num_wheel_pairs` and creating same number of `<left_joint>` and `<right_joint>` tags

```
<gazebo>
  <plugin name="diff_drive_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_diff_drive.so">
    ...
    <num_wheel_pairs>2</num_wheel_pairs>
    <left_joint>left_front_wheel_joint</left_joint>
    <left_joint>left_rear_wheel_joint</left_joint>
    <right_joint>right_front_wheel_joint</right_joint>
    <right_joint>right_rear_wheel_joint</right_joint>
    ...
  </plugin>
</gazebo>
```